# Set Location of GBQ credentials when using IPython?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm using `pandas.read_gbq` to pull data from Google Big Query, in an IPython notebook. However, I put my IPython notebooks in a shared Google Drive folder so that other folks can see them as well.

When I've run the `read_gbq` command, a new browser window opens up asking me to authenticate, which works great. But then my credentials file gets dumped in the same folder where my notebook sits, which is not good!

How can I leave my credentials file somewhere safe (local)?